# Cannot pip udate numpy

Tags: numpy, pip

I want to update numpy from 1.19.1 to 1.19.2. So I did the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

However, I received the following error message:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/userdata/data-dlin/.conda/envs/mybase/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy-1.19.1.dist-info/RECORD'

I went to the directory and found the RECORD file was indeed missing. How do I fix the error?

Comment: Did you find how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstalling numpy (`pip uninstall numpy`), then deleting the entire folder

```
(python environment)/lib/site-packages/numpy-1.19.X.dist-info
```

And reinstalling `numpy` (`pip install numpy`) fixed it for me.